# customdata in playready license challenge on samsung smart tv

Tags: drm, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, playready

What is the working approach to put custom data into the license challenge for playready von Samsung smart TV? I have tried all suggsted ways but it seems like the PR Server does not receive it. Wireshark traces show nothing. How can I bestdebug this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

See chapter 4.1 in this document http://www.samsungdforum.com/Common/FileDownLoad?BoardType=6b8cf359de61b749&fileID=d9a7eda5f65a8700&ei=YjzNUsTLG8aS7Aa1sYH4Dw

> If you want to play PlayReady/WMDRM protected content, you should add predefined postfix
>   “|COMPONENT=WMDRM” to your original URL.

Comment: This is known to me. The problem is specific to custom data:  playerPlugin.InitPlayer(url+”|COMPONENT=WMDRM”);
playerPlugin.SetPlayerProperty (3, customdata, customdata.length);
playerPlugin.StartPlayback(); does not show any custom data